# Query view data in Tableau REST API 2.6

Tags: tableau-api

I know that we can query view data through REST API in tableau. In the documentation, I see this is available only from tableau server ver. 10.5 (api/2.8). I have the requirement to get the data in sheets for tableau server ver. 10.3 (api/2.6). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't.

An alternative solution is to directly download from datasources. This service only requires api version of 2.5.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm#download_data_source